# How to pass user_id for importing excel using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, excel-import

I have a problem with excel import using Laravel.
The user wants import excel of suppliers data into database.
The `suppliers` table got `user_id` but the user may not have their own `user_id`. So, when importing excel file the user use excel without `user_id` columns.
So I want to pass the `user_id` of that user and stored in database.

SuppliersImportController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;        
    Excel::import(new SuppliersImport($user_id), request()->file('file'));

    return  redirect('/suppliers')->withStatus('Excel file imported successfully');
}
```

SuppliersImport

```
public function  __construct($user_id)
{

    $this->user_id =$user_id;
}
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Supplier([
        'name' =>$row[0],
        'phone' =>$row[1],
        'email' =>$row[2],
        'address' =>$row[3],
        'city' =>$row[4],
        'country' =>$row[5],
        'customer' =>$row[6],
        'user_id'=> $this->user_id,         
        
    ]);
```

Error

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `suppliers` (`name`, `phone`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `country`, `customer`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (soe, 176893848, soe@mail.com, abc, Yangon, Myanmar, 1, 2020-11-27 12:15:08, 2020-11-27 12:15:08))

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is `user_id` set as "fillable" on the model, Supplier?

Comment: nope. i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do  is

```
public function model(array $row)
{    
    $user = auth()->user();  //Get the current user 
    return new Supplier([
        'name' =>$row[0],
        'phone' =>$row[1],
        'email' =>$row[2],
        'address' =>$row[3],
        'city' =>$row[4],
        'country' =>$row[5],
        'customer' =>$row[6],
        'user_id'=> $user->id,      // add their user id when importing    
        
    ]);
```

Comment: i have same situation i want to pass a variable but not auth (current user).

Comment: you can use the similar method to pass the variable.